# I am getting "Invalid cursor state" error in my code. I have used next() before accessing resultset still getting same error

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc-odbc

I am getting error whenever i try to store value of rsc.getString(2) in valut.

```
ArrayList<Integer> rowc = new ArrayList<>();
         System.out.println("Select timing," + dayname + " from " + classid);
         rsc = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE).executeQuery("Select timing," + dayname + " from " + classid);
         String valut="";
                                while (rsc.next()) {
                                   valut=rsc.getString(2);
                                    if (!valut.equals("")) {


                                        //valut=rsc.getString(2);
                                       // if(rsc.getString(2).contains("LEC") ||rsc.getString(2).contains("prac") || rsc.getString(2).contains("tut"))
                                       // if(!valut.contains("LEC") && (valut.contains("prac") || valut.contains("tut")) && !valut.contains("LEC(1)"))
                                        if(valut.contains("LEC") ||valut.contains("prac") || valut.contains("tut"))
                                        { rowc.add(rsc.getRow());
                                        rsc.next();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: why do you have `rsc.next();` in your if?

Comment: So that if following condition satisfies i can then access next to next row.

Comment: @SMA please check my comment.

Comment: That's already been done by your while loop, so no meaning in advancing twice?

Comment: I have to do I twice like for 1st row if condition satisfies I have to access 3rd row